# http to https apache redirection .. Infinite Loop

Tags: apache, redirect

Environment: CentOS
Apache Version: Apache/2.2.15

I have been trying to force my website to be https but encounter Infinite redirects

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias example 

SetEnv HTTPS on
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/

SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /ssl/star_ecom_sanmar_com.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /ssl/star_ecom_sanmar_com.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /ssl/DigiCertCA.crt
SSLProxyEngine on
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com localhost

ServerAlias example
DocumentRoot ......

DirectoryIndex index.shtml index.html index.jsp
AddType text/html .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php4

CustomLog /var/log/httpd/access_log combined env=!dontlog
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond "%{HTTPS}" !="on"
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
....
```

Above rewrite rule is always executed even after redirection to https is done causing an infinite loop which makes me think that the value of {HTTPS} is never updated. same is the case with {SERVER_PORT} which is always 80 even when request is from https.
Below is output from php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html><head>
<style type="text/css">
body {background-color: #ffffff; color: #000000;}
body, td, th, h1, h2 {font-family: sans-serif;}
pre {margin: 0px; font-family: monospace;}
a:link {color: #000099; text-decoration: none; background-color: #ffffff;}
a:hover {text-decoration: underline;}
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
.center {text-align: center;}
.center table { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: left;}
.center th { text-align: center !important; }
td, th { border: 1px solid #000000; font-size: 75%; vertical-align: baseline;}
h1 {font-size: 150%;}
h2 {font-size: 125%;}
.p {text-align: left;}
.e {background-color: #ccccff; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;}
.h {background-color: #9999cc; font-weight: bold; color: #000000;}
.v {background-color: #cccccc; color: #000000;}
.vr {background-color: #cccccc; text-align: right; color: #000000;}
img {float: right; border: 0px;}
hr {width: 600px; background-color: #cccccc; border: 0px; height: 1px; color: #000000;}
</style>
<title>phpinfo()</title><meta name="ROBOTS" content="NOINDEX,NOFOLLOW,NOARCHIVE" /></head>
<body><div class="center">
<h2>PHP Variables</h2>
<table border="0" cellpadding="3" width="600">
<tr class="h"><th>Variable</th><th>Value</th></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["dontlog"]</td><td class="v">1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SCRIPT_URL"]</td><td class="v">test.php</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]</td><td class="v">test.php</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]</td><td class="v">example.com</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS"]</td><td class="v">1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]</td><td class="v">Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT"]</td><td class="v">text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING"]</td><td class="v">gzip, deflate, sdch, br</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"]</td><td class="v">en-US,en;q=0.8</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]</td><td class="v">::1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST"]</td><td class="v">example.com</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER"]</td><td class="v">example.com</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["HTTP_CONNECTION"]</td><td class="v">Keep-Alive</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["PATH"]</td><td class="v">/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SERVER_SIGNATURE"]</td><td class="v">&lt;address&gt;Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at example.com Port 80&lt;/address&gt;
</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"]</td><td class="v">Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]</td><td class="v">example.com</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SERVER_ADDR"]</td><td class="v">::1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]</td><td class="v">80</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]</td><td class="v">::1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]</td><td class="v">.....</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SERVER_ADMIN"]</td><td class="v">root@localhost</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"]</td><td class="v">test.php</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["REMOTE_PORT"]</td><td class="v">57954</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["GATEWAY_INTERFACE"]</td><td class="v">CGI/1.1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]</td><td class="v">HTTP/1.1</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]</td><td class="v">GET</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]</td><td class="v"><i>no value</i></td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]</td><td class="v">test.php</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]</td><td class="v">test.php</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]</td><td class="v">test.php</td></tr>
<tr><td class="e">_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"]</td><td class="v">1483559123</td></tr>
</table><br />
</div></body></html>
```

Please advise

Comment: Tried below condition also but still get infinite redirect loop.  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
 RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
RewriteCond "%{HTTPS}" !="on"
```

To this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
```

And don't set it yourself with SetEnv, mod_rewrite takes care of it.

That redirect is in your `<VirtualHost>` for port 80 though so I don't see how it could be processed if coming in on https (the check shouldn't be even needed because of that) since the other virtual host would be processed in that case. Are you sure you don't have a `.htaccess` with some rules in that you've overlooked? Otherwise, please post your full virtual host blocks. And also clear your cache or try a different browser.

Comment: Tried the above mentioned solution but still the same.. The rule is executed in a loop

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.. This was all because of a wrong configuration..

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost/
```

was calling the port 80 VirtualHost internally (ServerName is localhost) and hence the redirect loop.
This was fixed by replacing the above with

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8409/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8409/
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this had to do with CloudFlare's "flexible" SSL/TSL encryption mode. Setting it to "full" resolved my redirect loop.